# Booting OS X from flash-drive. Possible to install OS X on that flash-drive only?

Tags: macos, mac, usb-flash-drive, osx-yosemite

I created an OS X flash drive. When booting from the flash-drive on my mac, it is the installation process. Can I install OS X on that flash drive (16GB) or does it have to install on my mac?

I don't want to install this version of OS X on my Mac yet, but I want to try it.

Comment: keep in mind that os x uses more than 16GB of space so a external HDD may be better than a Stick

Comment: I've installed mavericks on a usb 3 flashdrive and it was painfully slow.

Comment: you need to buy the fastest stick you can afford. I repurposed a stick that shipped with Windows on it and it was fast, but still too slow to be considered usable.

But for my money, I'd use VMware Fusion or VirtualBox. You get better performance and the ability to snapshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. for more detail:
http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1948
But do remember that flash drive has read/write cycle, don't want to break you flash drive by installing it there. Other option would be installing to external hard drive.